# Electrical light switch circuit split

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, porch

I have one inside switch that turns on 3 porch lights. I would like to install a ceiling fan where the middle light is but do not want the other two lights on the same circuit to turn on. How can I separate the switch control?

Answer (score 4):

You would need to add a new wire from a new switch for the ceiling fan. If the (required) fan-rated box that will be installed is large enough you can simply leave the splice for the center light in that box just capped off.